# Filter with an else clause (numpy.where)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sure it's been asked and it's going to get a "just use a generator comprehension!" response, but just in case it's in the standard library somewhere and I just can't find it in itertools...

In Python 3.x, is there a functional alternative to:

```
(x if c else y for c, x, y in zip(cs, xs, ys))
```

For example, `numpy.where(cs, xs, ys)` does exactly this.

Comment: What's wrong with `numpy.where(cs, xs, ys)`? If it is not in the standard language, use an appropriate library or write the method you proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a generator expression, so just unwrap it:

```
cs = [True, False, True]
xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = [10, 20, 30]

def generator(cs, xs, ys):
    for c, x, y in zip(cs, xs, ys):
        yield x if c else y

print(list(x if c else y for c, x, y in zip(cs, xs, ys)))
print(list(generator(cs, xs, ys)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 20, 3]
[1, 20, 3]
```

Comment: For my own benefit: is there a difference between using zip and itertools.izip in your for statement?

Comment: Becasue in Python 3 I can't (and didn't need to) use it. In Python 2, `ixip()` is like `zip()` except that it returns an iterator instead of a list. It's gone in Python 3's `itertools` because that's what `zip()` in that version already does. Technically iterator objects are generator objects. I didn't bother to mention all this because your question has the `python-3.x` tag,

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, what about something like this? (I'm in Python 2.7.3, but I don't think it matters here.)

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[10,20,30]
>>> cond=[True, False, True]
>>> func=lambda c,x,y: x if c else y
>>> test=it.starmap(func, it.izip(cond,a,b))
>>> test.next()
1
>>> test.next()
20
>>> test.next()
3
```